# css animation in two separate classes

Tags: css, animation, background, less, background-color

The issue seems to be simple.

Using this code the animation works:

```
<div class="merged" ></div>
.merged {
     width:20rem;
     height:20rem;
     background: linear-gradient(297deg, #413f3d, #373533, #413f47, #8f6fee);
     color: @step4 !important;

     background-size: 800% 800%;
     animation: animbg 6s ease infinite;
     @keyframes animbg { 
         0%{background-position:0% 26%}
         50%{background-position:100% 75%}
         100%{background-position:0% 26%}
     }

}
```

And when the anim is separated into another class, it doesn't:

```
<div class="colors animation" ></div>
.colors {
     width:20rem;
     height:20rem;
     background: linear-gradient(297deg, #413f3d, #373533, #413f47, #8f6fee);
     color: @step4 !important;
     }

.animation{
     background-size: 800% 800%;
     animation: animbg 6s ease infinite;
     @keyframes animbg { 
         0%{background-position:0% 26%}
         50%{background-position:100% 75%}
         100%{background-position:0% 26%}
     }

}
```

#### To do:

How to make the animation work and serve it as a separate class?

Thank you

Comment: Both works for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amNwBx

Comment: I use Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 and I cannot make it work even if I add prefixed definitions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `@keyframes` outside of the `.animation` class?

Comment: I have tried this solution. Didn't work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious.  I think I have your animation working well
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BLzYxB

Tested on OSX Safari and Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

The CSS is exactly the same as what you've posted except that I explicitly defined a value for the variable `@step4` on line 1. I'm not sure what your intention was for this colour so I chose a value from your animation.

Hope this helps!